# Windows sets: how can I make 'New tab' in Powershell launch Powershell, rather than Edge?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I am running Windows 10 version 17661, which has the 'Sets' feature enabled.

[image]

After starting Powershell 6, and clicking **New tab**, I get an Edge tab instead of powershell.

[image]

**How can I make 'New tab' launch Powershell, rather than Edge?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current version of Sets you'll need to type the name of the app to start into **Search the web and windows** - there's no way to immediately start another tab of the same type.

[image]